# res status 500. Message: Internal server error find product by name and price

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to find products by name and price. It doesn't execute an error at execution time. But I've got error on postman.

I only want is finding name or price from the product.

I put name in one method and price in other as params

this is my product model:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const { Schema } = mongoose;

    const productSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   description: String,
   brand: String,
   price: Number,
   availableStock: Number,
   code: Number,
   isPassed: Boolean,
   createdAt: Date,
   passedAt: Date
    });

 mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

And these are my product routes

find product by name

```js
     app.get('/api/products/:name', async(req,res) =>{

        try{
      const name = req.params.name;

      const product = await Product.findOne({product : name});

      if(product){
        res.send(product);
      }
      else{
        res.status(404).send({ message: `product's name: '${name}' couldn't be 
    found ` });
      }

    }catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({ message: `Internal Server Error.\n\n${err}` });
    }

      });
```

find products by price

```js
    app.get('/api/products/:price', async(req,res) =>{

    try{
      const price = req.params.price;

      const products = await Product.find({products : price});

      if(products){
        res.send(products);
      }
      else{
        res.status(404).send({message:`Products with price: '${price}' 
    couldn't be found`})
      }

       }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({ message: `Internal server error.\n\n${err}` });
      }

      });
```

I expect the product found by name or price, but in the case of name this is the result:

{
    "message": "Internal Server Error.\n\nCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"P1\" at path \"_id\" for model \"products\""
}
And by last, In the case of price this is the result:

{
    "message": "Internal Server Error.\n\nCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"500\" at path \"_id\" for model \"products\""
}

Comment: Can you share a picture of what you're posting in postman, please?

Comment: I haven't got available postman, but I only want is finding product's name, and by other way finding product's price.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try changing

```
const product = await Product.findOne({product : name});
const product = await Product.findOne({product : price});
```

for

```
const product = await Product.findOne({name : name});
const product = await Product.findOne({price : price});
```

I mean, using the name of the schema for each parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Look like you're having a route `/api/products/:id` to find product by id put before your find by name and price route so when you get, for example "/api/products/500", it go to the id route and take "500" as `req.params.id`.

Also, define 2 route like `/api/products/:name` and `/api/products/:price` is not a good idea because it will not know when to go to name or price route but always go to the route that defined first.

I suggest using one route, like `/api/products/search` and use `req.query` to search instead of `req.params` (ex: "/api/products/search?name=test&price=500").

**Note**: Need to define this route before id route.